# .Net MVC 3 Adding Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am sure there is a very simple answer to this question, I think am just having trouble. I have animation.js file. It also has a include folder with dependency_1.js and dependency_2.js. In my animation.js file I do load dependency_1.js and dependency_2.js relative to my animation.js file.

In my _Layout.cshtml file I do have:

```
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
```

And I did place within my view SomeView.cshtml

```
@section JavaScript
{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/animation.js")"</script> }
```

But when my animate.js file calls the dependency_1.js file I get a 404 Not Found - http://localhost:14611/includes/dependency_1.js"

Im guessing it has to do with the url routing to the Scripts folder in my MVC project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths in Javascript files are relative to the HTML page, not the source Javascript.
You need to use an absolute path.

Comment: I can see how that works, MVC3 lets you place @Url.Content("~/Content/style.css") to get a path no matter what view you are using. I have added js to several views with no problem. Yet, I cant place this attribute within my js file. to use the dependency_1.js. Is there anything I can put (maybe my web.config) so that every view has access to these particular js files?

Comment: The simplest answer would be to include them explicitly in `<script>` tags.  Other than that, you could use an inline `<script>` to declare `var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~/")";`